# Plot difference in values of multiple variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have dataframe `DF` that shows the performance of different students in two tests, `test1` and `test2`:

```
DF <- data.frame(student = factor(c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5")), 
                 test1 = factor(c(90, 77, 45, 67, 80)),
                 test2 = factor(c(70, 75, 55, 64, 80)))
```

I want to plot student performance over time, i.e. across the two tests in a plot that looks like this, but with `student` instead of `series` and tests instead of `time` (so (`test1` and test2`, rather than for example the numbers 2 and 4) on the x axis:[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to compare the scores over time would be to convert the data into long format and create a bar-plot side by side.

```
library(ggplot2)

tidyr::pivot_longer(DF, cols = -student) %>%
   ggplot() + aes(x = student, y = as.numeric(as.character(value)), fill = name) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.4, position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Maybe you are looking for this

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(DF, cols = -student) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x = name, y = as.numeric(as.character(value)), 
            group = student, color = student) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What this does is show how individual students' performance has changed, but making sense of the broader trends between the tests, which is what I want to show, is more difficult here than in the plot showed in my original question.

Comment: @KaC This shows `student performance over time` i.e different tests as mentioned in the question. Is it not what you want?

Comment: What I want is plot like the one in the original question.

Comment: @KaC Updated the answer. Can you check if this is what you want ?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, @ronak-shah. Thank you.